# Difference between $H(\omega)$ and $H(j\omega)$

Tags: frequency-response, impulse-response

What is the difference between $H(\omega)$ and $H(j\omega)$, in terms of impulse response. And if so, when do I have to use one or another.

Comment: See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26941/how-frequency-response-related-to-a-transfer-function